# Generate Runbook - Error during listVcVms

Tags: google-compute-engine

When we try to generate a Runbook , the Migrate for Compute engine web console shows the following error:

"Error during listVCVms: Internal server error"

We can´t continue with the runbook generation process after this error message.

We have a VMware vCenter environment as a data source.

We have read the system logs but unfortunately we couldn´t find the rootcause.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Could you please help us?

Thanks in advance.

Carlos Plaza

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes from VMs created before vSphere version 5.0 due to a missing value in the "config.firmware" property. If this isn't the cause of the issue then I'd suggest opening an [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with Google to dive further into it.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for your help. We have a VMware vCenter Server 6.5.